# Firestore addSnapshot create multiple duplicate when change data at the back end

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Please see my Firestore data Structures:

[image: my data structures]

I have successfully downloaded it and mapped to the SwiftUI data structure.

My issue - when I change the data at the backend (e.g. delete one of the drinks document) the addsnapshot listener will create multiple duplicate data.

Please see the photos:

Before change:
[image: before change]

After backend changes:
[image: after backend changes]

My code is as follows:

```
class ActiveViewModel : ObservableObject {
    static let instance = ActiveViewModel()
    @Published var activeTables : [TableSummary] = []
    @Published var currentSelectTable : TableSummary = TableSummary(id: "", drink: [], alacarte: [], mealdeal: [])
    init(){
        //        fetchActiveTable()
        //        fetchactivetableData()
        
    }
//    func getDrinkInddex(item: CartDrinkVM) -> Int {
//        let index = self.cartDrinks.firstIndex { i in
//            return item.id == i.id
//        } ?? 0
//        return index
//    }
    
    func getMealDealIndex(item: FirebaseMealDeal) -> Int {
        let index = self.currentSelectTable.mealdeal.firstIndex { i in
            return item.id == i.id
        } ?? 0
        return index
    }
    
    func fetchactivetableData(){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        var drinks : [FirebaseDrink] = []
        var alacarte : [FirebaseAlacarte] = []
        var mealdeal : [FirebaseMealDeal] = []
        
        db.collection("Active Table")
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                guard let document = querySnapshot?.documents else {return}
                self.activeTables = []
                for doc in document {
                    let docID = doc.documentID
                    let tableReference = db.collection("Active Table").document(docID)
                    let drinkReference = tableReference.collection("Drinks")
                    let mealReference = tableReference.collection("Meal Deal")
                    let alacarteReference = tableReference.collection("Alacarte")
                    alacarteReference.addSnapshotListener { alacarteQuerySnapshot, error in
                        guard let alacarteDocument = alacarteQuerySnapshot?.documents else {return}
                        alacarte = alacarteDocument.compactMap({ alacarteDocumentSnapshot in
                            let foodID = alacarteDocumentSnapshot.documentID
                            let data = alacarteDocumentSnapshot.data()
                            let detail = data["Food"] as? [[String : Any]] ?? []
                            
                            var foodDetail : [FBAlacartedetail] = []
                            for i in detail {
                                foodDetail.append(FBAlacartedetail(name: i["name"] as? String ?? "", price: i["price"] as? Double ?? 0.00, quantity: i["quantity"] as? Int ?? 0, extra: i["extra"] as? [String] ?? []))
                            }
                            
                            return FirebaseAlacarte(id: foodID, food: foodDetail)
                        })
                        
                            mealReference.addSnapshotListener { mealQuerySnapshot, error in
                                guard let mealDocument = mealQuerySnapshot?.documents else {return}
                                mealdeal = mealDocument.compactMap({ mealdealQueryDocumentSnapshot in
                                    let mealdealID = mealdealQueryDocumentSnapshot.documentID
                                    let data = mealdealQueryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                                    let price = data["price"] as? Double ?? 0.00
                                    let quantity = data["quantity"] as? Int ?? 0
                                    let isOrdered = data["isOrdered"] as? Bool ?? false
                                    let starter = data["starter"] as! [[String : Any]]
                                    let secondCourse = data["secondCourse"] as! [[String : Any]]
                                    let mainCourse = data["mainCourse"] as! [[String: Any]]
                                    var starterfood : [Firebaseitem] = []
                                    var secondCoursefood : [Firebaseitem] = []
                                    var mealcoursefood : [Firebaseitem] = []
                                    
                                    for i in mainCourse {
                                        mealcoursefood.append(Firebaseitem(id: i["id"] as? String ?? "", name: i["name"] as? String ?? "", extra: i["extra"] as? [String] ?? []))
                                    }
                                    for i in starter {
                                        starterfood.append(Firebaseitem(id: i["id"] as? String ?? "", name: i["name"] as? String ?? "", extra: i["extra"] as? [String] ?? []))
                                    }
                                    
                                    for i in secondCourse {
                                        secondCoursefood.append(Firebaseitem(id: i["id"] as? String ?? "", name: i["name"] as? String ?? "", extra: i["extra"] as? [String] ?? []))
                                    }
                                    
                                    return FirebaseMealDeal(id: mealdealID, show: true, starter: starterfood, secondCourse: secondCoursefood, mainCourse: mealcoursefood, price: price, quantity: quantity, isOrdered: isOrdered)
                                })
                                drinkReference.addSnapshotListener { drinkQuerySnapshot, error in
                                    guard let drinkDocument = drinkQuerySnapshot?.documents else {return}
                                    drinks = drinkDocument.compactMap({ drinkDocumentQuerySnap in
                                        let drinkID = drinkDocumentQuerySnap.documentID
                                        let data = drinkDocumentQuerySnap.data()
                                        let detail = data["Drinks"] as? [[String : Any]] ?? []
                                        var drinkdetail : [FirebaseDrinkDetail] = []
                                        for i in detail {
                                            drinkdetail.append(FirebaseDrinkDetail(name: i["Name"] as? String ?? "", price: i["Price"] as? Double ?? 0.00, unit: i["Unit"] as? Int ?? 0))
                                        }
                                        return FirebaseDrink(id: drinkID, detail: drinkdetail)
                                    })
                                self.activeTables.append(TableSummary(id: docID, drink: drinks, alacarte: alacarte, mealdeal: mealdeal))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
}
```